# What means supporting surface in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, word-in-context

I interpret ambiguously the highlighted phrase (supporting surface), what really means?

> **lie<sup>1</sup>** /lī/
> I. *verb* — [no *obj.*]
> 1. (of a person or animal) be in or assume a horizontal or resting position on a **supporting surface**
> • *the man lay face downward on the grass*
> • *I had to **lie down** for two hours because I was groggy*
> • Lily lay back on the pillows and watched him.
>
> (The New Oxford American Dictionary)

[image]

I have two possible definitions that come in my mind:

- A surface that's supported e.g.

[image]

- Or means a surface that is capable to support something
- Other

Comment: Please include a transcription of image text, as images cannot be searched (among other issues). Often, images of text aren't necessary unless a transcription cannot adequately convey the context. See [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You've highlighted just a part of the definition of a verb.
The the entire definition is

1. (of a person or animal) be in or assume a horizontal or resting position on a supporting surface.

That means that when a person **lies**, they take a position on a supporting surface, such as a bed, or the surface of the earth.

This is not the definition of a supporting surface, but of the action of the person or animal.
The surface in your picture is not one where a person or animal could "lie" (unless it were a kitten), and in any case it's an object, not the action of a verb.

**A "supporting surface" is a surface that supports something, for example, someone who lies on it.**

It seems like that question could have been asked without huge distracting graphics.